# What options are available to test flex/flash with Perl?

Tags: apache-flex, perl, testing, functional-testing

I'm currently using Selenium RC with Test::More & Test::WWW::Selenium to conduct GUI testing of a web app. Are there any similiar tools/Perl modules that I can use to test flex/flash components? Thanks.

Comment: What modules does CPAN suggest?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org is a wonderful thing.

Comment: @Ether: Yes, search.cpan.org is a wonderful thing; I checked there and a few other places before posting my question on SO. 
@Zaid: Didn't find any suggestions on CPAN.

Comment: Yes, seems like you're looking for a unique requirement...

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to test Flex apps using Perl. Selenium works using Javascript, so if your Flex has an ExternalInterface that can be used to test, you could use Selenium.

Your best bet for testing your Flex app would be FlexUnit. It has ways to automate GUI testing.